# Problem setting custom validation rules in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, validation

I creating a custom validation rule in my cakephp model.

```
        'article' => array(
                'rule' => '/^[a-z0-9#.,&; ]{2,255}$/i',
                'required' => true,
                'allowEmpty' => false,
                'message' => 'Alphabets and numbers only(3,255).'
        ),
```

This works fine. But It stops working, throws a error in model, when I add forward slash **`[/]`**. I can't understand why forward causes a problem.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Adding a slash to the validation rule leads to the error? Or having a slash in the input field? Also, can you post the error itself?

Comment: iirc it has special meaning for regex, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in your other question, read about [`preg_match()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) patterns in the php manual. This function is used internally in the framework.